# 2 identical JMS listeners are implemented instead of the 1st. ActiveMQ And cannot transmit and receive the object

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, jms-serializer

I am writing an application in Spring (I do not use Spring Boot). The application uses the JMS broker ActiveMQ.

Listener:

```java
@Component
public class ReceiveMessage {

    private HistoryService historyService;

    @Autowired
    public void setHistoryService(HistoryService historyService) {

        this.historyService = historyService;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "my_topic")
    public void receiveMessage(ObjectMessage objectMessage) throws JMSException {

        Object object = ((ObjectMessage) objectMessage).getObject();
        System.out.println(object);
        if(objectMessage.getObject() instanceof History) {
            History history = (History) objectMessage.getObject();
            try {
                historyService.add(history);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Message Producer:

```java
@Component
public class MessageProducer {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(History history) {
        jmsTemplate.send("my_topic", new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(history);
                return objectMessage;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

JMS Config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycomp")
public class JMSConfig {

    String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    String BROKER_USERNAME = "admin";
    String BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin";

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setPubSubDomain(true); // для работы с topic
        //утсановка места назначения для отправки и приема по умалчанию
        // Destination defaultDestination = new ActiveMQTopic("my_topic");
        // template.setDefaultDestination(defaultDestination);

        return template;
    }



    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");

        factory.setPubSubDomain(true); // для работы с topic
        return factory;
    }
}
```

History class:

```java
@Entity (name = "History")
@Table(name = "HISTORY", schema = "PUBLIC")
public class History implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CHANGETYPE")
    private String changeType;

    @Column(name = "CHANGEENTITY")
    private String changeEntity;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

    public History(){
    }
    //..
    //setters getters
```

ActiveMQ:

[image]

Problems:

1. instead of 1 listener, 2 listeners are implemented.
2. I cannot cast an object when receiving a message to the type History.

I tried to see what is sent and received in debug mode

Sending in the MessageProducer:

[image]

That's what the listener gets:

[image]

But it seems that some data is here:

[image]

Comment: I recommend you avoid using `javax.jms.ObjectMessage`. They depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload which is generally considered unsafe because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this which is why most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. For example, here's the related documentation for [ActiveMQ 5.x](https://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage).

Comment: If possible, instead of using `javax.jms.ObjectMessage` define a data representation for the payload (JSON, protobuf, XML) and use a `javax.jms.TextMessage` or `javax.jms.BytesMessage` to carry it. There are a number of other issues with use JMS ObjectMessage not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/) as well.